# Space in path in a shell script

Tags: scripting

I have a variable 
    android="/media/New Volume_/android-sdk-linux_86"

I get an error saying that it cannot find the directory

I changed it to android="/media/New\ Volume_/android-sdk-linux_86"

I still get the same error. I even tried

android="/media/'New Volume_'/android-sdk-linux_86"
 and I am using "$android" everywhere ...

I am not able to find the error, can someone help me..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take it this is bash? You assign variables with spaces like this:

```
android="/media/New Volume_/android-sdk-linux_86"
```

(Note you don't use the $ notation when setting a value.)

And reference them like this:

```
cd "$android"
```

Comment: it's possible you have spaces either side of the = sign? what is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: it's also possible that the directory indeed doesn't exist at the time the script is run and the variable is referenced. have you checked?

Comment: yes ,I checked it ..I donot have spaces on either side of = sign and the folder does exist. The error is ./run.sh: line 30: /media/New: No such file or directory

Comment: if you cut and paste the exact code I'd have more of a chance of telling you what was wrong.

Comment: I got the answer ... There s no need to put an escape charater inside the quotes. Thanks for your help.